# Convert varchar to double fails when I use ADO yet it works in MS Access

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access, ado

I have made a query that ran successfully in the first version of my program, using ADO and C++ to query MS Access 2007 database.

However, the structure of my database had to be modified.

Fields that were once of type double are now varchar.

When I execute the same query on the modified database, it reports data type mismatch, as it should.

**EDITED QUERY TO HELP THE POSTER OF THE FIRST SOLUTION:**

Here is simplified version of my query:

```
wchar_t query = L" select ( ads(Field) + Field ) / 2 from MyTable where PrimaryKey = 1;";
```

Field was of type double, but now is varchar.

I have tried using `CDbl` like this:

```
wchar_t query = L" select ( abs( CDbl(Field) ) + CDbl(Field) ) / 2 from MyTable where PrimaryKey = 1;";
```

It works when I create query in MS Access, but in my program I still get data type mismatch error reported.

I have tried to find alternative on the Internet, and have thought that CAST or CONVERT can sole this, but it seems that they do not work in MS Access.

Is there any solution for this ?

Thank you.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to convert the value to Double not in the query but **after** the query has been run?

CAST and CONVERT are not Access SQL functions

I dont use c++ but even with a small subroutine in Access using the ADO object I cannot reproduce the error...

```
Sub test()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim db As ADODB.Connection

Set db = CurrentProject.Connection

rs.Open "SELECT (Abs(CDbl(Field))+CDbl(Field))/2 AS A FROM MyTable;", db

While rs.EOF = False
Debug.Print rs!A


rs.MoveNext
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: If you suggest some code showing how, you might get some ticks otherwise this looks like a question,

Comment: @Wietze314, I have updated my question, since I believe it is relevant for your solution to be able to see the full query.

Comment: I dont use c++ but even with a small subroutine in Access using the ADO object I cannot reproduce the error...

    Sub test()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim db As ADODB.Connection
    
    Set db = CurrentProject.Connection
    
    rs.Open "SELECT (Abs(CDbl(Field))+CDbl(Field))/2 AS A FROM MyTable;", db
    
    While rs.EOF = False
    Debug.Print rs!A * 1.01
    
    
    rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    
End Sub

Comment: I see... This query is the part of the larger function which uses OLE Automation to populate Excel. Maybe there lies type mismatch. I will check and report my results as soon as possible. Thank you. Regards.

Comment: @Wietze314, You were right, everything works just fine! Query was fired when user presses first button, yet I have pressed second button. Code for that button is similar as the code for first one. I guess fatigue did its job... After pressing the correct button I have seen that everything works well myself. Thank you, without your test, I would not be able to verify that my code works well. That led me to try again that query which led to the solution for my problem. That is why you have +1 from me. Thank you so much! Regards.